# CARA Utility function expected utility

Tags: utility-theory

I have been trying to undestand how the expected utility for a CARA negative exponential Utility function is calculated. In my particular case the variable has normally distributed returns.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 3):

[CARA Utility function](http://economics.about.com/library/glossary/bldef-cara-utility.htm) $u(c)=\frac{-e^{-ac}}{a}$ for $a>0.$

[Expected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value) utility $E(u(c))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(c) f(c) dc,$ where f is a [density](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function).

Example f(10)=0.3, f(20)=0.7, else f=0 and a=2.
Then
$E(u(c))=0.3\times u(10)+0.7\times u(20)=0.3\times \frac{-e^{-2*10}}{2}+0.7\times \frac{-e^{-2*20}}{2}$

Now, for normal density $f(c)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\; e^{-c^2/2}$ we have $E(u(c))=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(c) f(c) dc=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{-e^{-ac}}{a} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\; e^{-c^2/2} dc=\frac{-1}{a\sqrt{2\pi}}\; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ac} e^{-c^2/2} dc=\frac{-1}{a\sqrt{2\pi}}\; \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ac-c^2/2} dc.$

Here the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-ac-c^2/2} dc$ can be solved with help of the solution $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-Ax^2} e^{-2Bx}\,dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{A}}e^{\frac{B^2}{A}} \quad (A>0)$ from the [list of integrals of exponential functions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_exponential_functions)

Comparison yields A=0.5, B=0.5a, thus $E(u(c))=\frac{-1}{a\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{0.5}}e^{\frac{(0.5a)^2}{0.5}}=\frac{-1}{a\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{2\pi}e^{\frac{0.25a^2}{0.5}}=\frac{-e^{0.5a^2}}{a}$

And this can be [nicely plotted with Wolfram alpha.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-e%5E%280.5%2aa%5E2%29/a%20%28a%20from%200%20to%203%29) Does your solution confirm this?